# $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Using auto complete in jquery. I am facing a problem which

> TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

I included all the necessary script files. I am not able to understand where I made the mistake. How can I resolve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.hashchange.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.tools.min.js" ></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#namanyay-search-box').keyup(function (e) {
        var searched = $('#namanyay-search-box').val()
        $.getJSON('get_data', 'title=' + searched, function (result) {
            var elements = [];
            $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                elements.push(val.merchant_name)
            })

            $('#namanyay-search-box').autocomplete({
                source: elements
            })
        })
    });

    var indicator = $('#indicator'),
        indicatorHalfWidth = indicator.width() / 2,
        lis = $('#tabs').children('li');

    $("#tabs").tabs("#content section", {
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeOutSpeed: 0,
        fadeInSpeed: 400,
        onBeforeClick: function (event, index) {
            var li = lis.eq(index),
                newPos = li.position().left + (li.width() / 2) - indicatorHalfWidth;
            indicator.stop(true).animate({
                left: newPos
            }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you include jQuery twice/multiple versions?

Comment: i fail to see where you include the `jquery.autocomplete` file

Comment: in which of these "neccessary files" do you think `$().autocomplete` should be? I think you're missing one.

Comment: Where do you include the jQuery UI? is that supposed to be the second include? IF so, poor naming is suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download this http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js and place it in assets and add the code below

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library, include the script and css files from jQuery UI

Also remove the duplicate jquery library.