# JQuery UI - Autocomplete not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, import

I am getting the following error for the code below. I'm not quite sure how to fix the problem, but I know it likely has to do with the imports. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

**`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`**

**index.php:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }

    $("#birds").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit: This is not the same as some other related questions, since I'm importing the jquery-ui.js code. (I didn't forget it)

Edit:

Both of the following are true:

```
if (jQuery) {
alert("jquery is loaded");
} if (jQuery.ui) {
  alert("jquery UI is loaded");
}
```

Edit: jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/od1xd9L0/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(...).autocomplete is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696440/autocomplete-is-not-a-function)

Comment: It is not. The question you linked was about a missing script tag. The proper tag is in here.

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle to show it not working? Are the scripts loaded exactly as in your example?

Comment: Code seems to be fine. Only possible reason I see at the moment is, loading `jquery` file from online. Fiddle might help to look deeper.

Comment: Are your jquery and jquery UI scripts loading on your page?

Comment: I'm with amespower, check to make sure that the files are actually getting loaded properly using "view page source" and clicking the link for the file. Secondly, make sure that jQuery or jQueryUI is not getting loaded more than once.